# GraphQLResult of JSONObject have JSONString for object whose data type in schema file is JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, graphql, apollo-client

I am using a `GraphQL Apollo client` for my `swift iOS project`. During this I have faced some strange result when I got the response from the `fetch request` of `Apollo Client`.

My response is look like :

> {"getLeadList":{"totalrecord": 8.0,"totalpage": 1.0, "__typename":
>   "Customdatalist", "data":[{\n  \"testTextField_field_id\" : 53},\n 
>   \"textCheckBox\" : \"1\",\n  \"phones_field_id\" : 7,\n  \"owner\" :
>   [\n    {\n      \"srno\" : \"1\",\n      \"id\" : \"1\",\n
>   \"value\" : \"xy@gmail.com\",\n      \"name\" : \"Ashish\"\n    }\n 
>   ],\n  \"status_update_date\" : \"1583234662\”}]}}

So while parsing using `JSONDecoder().decode` it goes into the catch with error detail like `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`

Here you can see that server schema for this query response is as below.

[image]

And I have tried with many other queries, and in each response whenever Schema datatype for the `key` is `JSON` I faced this issue and not able to solve.

I know there is a solution with convert that String with .utf8 into data but this is not a good solution as some times I am not aware which key have this kind of JSONString. In one JSON response some keys have JSONString and some key have proper JSON formate data. So if any once have faced this please help me to out of this issue.

NOTE: The same query and response is working for Android and React Front end client. I am using Apollo client for communicating with the GraphQL server request and query.

Comment: Never `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a `DecodingError` catch block. Always `print(error)`. It tells you exactly what is wrong and even where. And please post code, not images.

Comment: @vadian Ok. Here is the error. `typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "getLeadList", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: The quoted JSON in the question is invalid and doesn't contain the key `getLeadList` mentioned in the error message. It seems that the JSON contains another (nested) JSON string as a value.

Comment: No actaully i have put the only half JSON in question there is a key of `getLeadList`. Here I have updated my question

Comment: The JSON is still invalid. Somewhere in the value for key `data` double quotes are missing. The error says the value is a string but you are going to decode a dictionary (in the screenshot even an array which is still more confusing).

Comment: @vadian yea i know it should be a object in `data` but in GraphQL response it automatically converts as a `string` this is the issue so i need help in this who have worked in `graphql` with this scenario.

Comment: Did you find a solution, I'm running into a similar issue. Is JSON defined as a custom scalar in your scheme?